# Pytorch is giving unsupported operand type error while gradient accumulation is turned off

Tags: python, pytorch

Pytorch code is giving an error of `unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float'.`

This error pops up when a leaf node is updated with an in-place operation. But I have mentioned `.no_grad()` before that.

Any help with this!

**Code:**

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

    class Network(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.hidden = nn.Linear(8, 125)
            self.output = nn.Linear(125, 1)
        
        def forward(self, x):
            x = 2*F.sigmoid(self.hidden(x))
            x = F.softmax(self.output(x), dim= 0)
            return x
        
        def loss(y_p,y):
            return ((y_p -y)**2).mean()
```

**Initialisation:**

```
x = torch.tensor([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0],[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0]] , dtype = torch.float32)
y = torch.tensor([2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0], dtype = torch.float32 )
w = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.1], dtype = torch.float32, requires_grad=True)

X_test = torch.tensor([5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0 , 5.0  , 5.0, 5.0, 5.0], dtype = torch.float32 )
lr = 0.001
n = 10
f = Network()
```

**Training:**

```
for epoch in range(n):
    
    y_pr = f(x)
    l = loss(y_pr,y)
    l.backward()

    with torch.no_grad():
        w -= lr*w.grad
        w.grad = None    
        

print(f(X_test))
```

**Error:**

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [199], in <cell line: 1>()
> 5     l.backward()
> 7     with torch.no_grad():
> ----> 8         w -= lr*w.grad
> 9         w.grad = None
> 12 print(f(X_test))
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Tensor `w` doesn't have any gradient because it hasn't been used during inference!

Comment: Sorry I could not follow! How else should I use it?

Comment: I don't know, you already have a model with parameters which you use to infer `y_pr`. What do you want to use `w` for exactly?

Comment: I wish to use 'w' as a weight vector which I can update during back-propagation using the loss function 'l'. In a way to minimise the loss function 'l'.

Comment: But my point is, your never using `w`. In "I wish to use it as a weight vector", you need to make it so it is actually used inside the `forward` function of `Network`.